# Can I easily upgrade from Debian Squeeze to Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, upgrade, debian

Is there an easy way to upgrade from Debian Squeeze to Ubuntu 12.04. The question is mainly targeted at a almost plain server installation of Squeeze. I do not have physical access to the box, so a reinstall via CD ROM /USB-Stick is not an option for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no easy way to "upgrade" from a CLI installation of Debian Squeeze to Ubuntu 12.04 (server variant or otherwise). i.e., you cannot just `dist-upgrade`.

If you have no physical access and this is a physical server, perhaps you can install Ubuntu via PXE? If this is a VPS of some kind, please detail and I can suggest some workarounds...